# Access-Control-Allow-Origin blocks attempts to load rss.xml

Tags: javascript, html, xml, google-chrome, rss

**I have read other posts on this, neither helped.**

I have javascript that is supposed to serve as simple RSS reader. Idea is I start a webpage with this javascript on it, it will access rss.xml on preset webpages, format it and present it in nicely looking way.
It works only for some webpages. On some I get the **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** warning with **Origin null not allowed**. It is happening even when I upload the HTML and JS to github pages and run it from there.
Is there a way around this? If most webpages are not accessible than this little exercise is pointless.
My javascript code:

```
function getRss (rss_url){
    if (rss_url == null){ return false; }

    var xmlHttp;
    xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status==200){
            document.getElementById("demo").innerText = xmlHttp.responseText;
            parseRss(xmlHttp.responseXML);
        }
    }

    xmlHttp.open("GET", rss_url, true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

TL;DR
I need to access rss.xml files on other sites using **javascript only**. I use **Chome** browser and code will be hosted on github pages.
Thanks for any tips.

Comment: see if you can set the origin to your webpage the JS is running on, and see if the server responds with the CORS allowing that domain. see here for further info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: you can't, but you could use YQL to turn the XML into JSONp